# WSL2 OpenAI Gym - render segmentation fault

Tags: python, windows, x11, wsl-2, openai-gym

I was trying to get gym to work on WSL2. I installed VcXsrv and configured it on Windows 11 according to the tutorials, pasted `export DISPLAY=$(ip route list default | awk '{print $3}'):0 export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1` to bashrc, added something to the Windows firewall. Xeyes works just fine but when I try to launch the program that uses gym, a black window (with correct name - Arcade Learning Environment) appears for a fraction of a second and then a segmentation fault happens. `A.L.E: Arcade Learning Environment (version 0.8.1+53f58b7) [Powered by Stella] Segmentation fault`.

Installing conda or different python versions didn't help. Checking or unchecking "Native opengl" in VcXsrv also doesn't seem to help. Do you have any idea what might be the reason and how to fix it? I can provide more information if needed but honestly I don't even know what might help - feel free to ask.